# Multirow multicolumn table

Tags: latex

I need to create the following table in LaTeX and I just cannot seem to get it right.

[image]

The text inside the cells is not centered correctly and the same goes for the "Eye movements" cell. Could any of you see what I doing wrong?

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc|c}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Response}} \\ 
& & unnatural & natural \\ \cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Eye movement}\end{sideways}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{sideways}unnatural\end{sideways}} & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} \\ \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                        &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{sideways}natural\end{sideways}} & 3 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4}   \\ \cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the pointer. I finally made it work with the following code:

```
\begin{table}[h]\centering
\def \BoxWidth {3.5cm}
\def \BoxHeight {2cm}
\def \SWidth {0.2cm}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\BoxWidth}}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\SWidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{\BoxWidth}}
\begin{tabular}{SSM|M}
~ & ~ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Response}} \\ 
~ & ~ & unnatural & natural  \\  \cline{3-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}{\textbf{Eye Movements}}\end{sideways}} 
~ & \begin{sideways}\parbox{\BoxHeight}{\centering unnatural}\end{sideways} 
&  \multicolumn{1}{|R|}{Command-based interfaces} &  \multicolumn{1}{R|}{Not Possible} \\ \cline{2-4}
~ & \begin{sideways}\parbox{\BoxHeight}{\centering natural}\end{sideways} 
& \multicolumn{1}{|R|}{Non-command interfaces} &  \multicolumn{1}{R|}{Virtual environments} \\  \cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikibooks documentation on LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) is very good, and you should take a look through [some of the numerous examples for different table formats](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables). Some of them only need to be modified slightly to reproduce your image.